# Using a samba file server, when using a 3TB drive, clients only see 68.2GB on the network location

Tags: server, hard-drive, files, samba

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 server 32-bit (no GUI). I am using this as a SOHO file server with only 1-3 users. I have set everything up properly and everything seems to work just fine. I am using a 3TB HDD to store videos (500mb-2gb per file)

My problem is that on a windows 7 workstation I see the share under Ubuntu in my networks. I have mapped the network drive to appear in my computer and when it appears it only shows 63.4 free of 68.2GB.

[image]

This is what fdisk -l is showing

```
Disk /dev/sda: 74.5 GiB, 80000000000 bytes, 156250000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    
Disklabel type: dos    
Disk identifier: 0x24a868d4    

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 145764351 145762304 69.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       145766398 156248063  10481666    5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       145766400 156248063  10481664    5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F3A30150-7E6D-4A72-92CD-A61A6D73C40E

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 5860532223 5860530176  2.7T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000146337792 bytes, 1953410816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, stupid me. I forgot to modify the fstab file. This is how I solved it.

Find your drive you want to mount by using

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I found that my device is named `/dev/sdb1` so I then typed

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

and enter in the following at the end of the page. (press <kbd>i</kbd>, make changes, then <kbd>esc</kbd> `:wq`)

```
/dev/yourdevicehere /yourmountpoint ext4 rw 0 0
```

Make sure you match your filesystem correctly (ext3, ext4..etc.)